# Change background color with OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

The Qt [OpenGL Window Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtopengl-openglwindow-example.html) shows a colored triangle. The colors, RGB corners, are set with:

```
static const GLfloat colors[] = {
    1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
};
```

How do I change the black background to another color?

Comment: See [`glClearColor`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml).

Comment: It is obvious that the color of the triangle has nothing to do with the color of the background. Even if you don't draw a triangle, the background will have a color. Then why do you show the 3 colors associated with the 3 vertices of the triangle? Anyway, this question could clearly be avoided with a little research effort.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You set the **clear color** with use of [`glClearColor`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClearColor.xhtml) function:

> ### C Specification
>
> ```c
> void glClearColor(GLfloat red, GLfloat green, GLfloat blue, GLfloat alpha);
> ```
>
> ### Parameters
>
> `red`, `green`, `blue`, `alpha`
>
> Specify the red, green, blue, and alpha values used when the color buffers are cleared. The initial values are all `0`.
>
> ### Description
>
> `glClearColor` specifies the red, green, blue, and alpha values used by [`glClear`](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glClear.xhtml) to clear the color buffers. Values specified by `glClearColor` are clamped to the range `[0,1]`.

As documentation suggests, the **clear color** is used when you clear the color buffer via `glClear` function (by specifying `GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT` argument):

```cpp
glClearColor(0, 1, 0, 1); // sets green color
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```